# I'm getting "Heroku push rejected, no Rails or Rack app detected" error w/ Sinatra app

Tags: ruby, heroku, sinatra

I used the example hello world app here:

http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rack

And get the error "Heroku push rejected, no Rails or Rack app detected"
Help?

Comment: It does work locally? Did you commit your changes before pushing to Heroku?

Answer (score 3):

You are missing a `config.ru` file. What you want to do is to create a file that looks like this: (it should be in the root of your repo)

```
# config.ru
require './your/app/file'

run MyApp
```

...where `MyApp` is your Sinatra app's class.

Be sure that your app file will not try to start (`MyApp.run!`) your app when *require*'d:

```
# your_app_file.rb

class MyApp < Sinatra::Base
  ...
end

# Only run it when called as `ruby your_app_file.rb`
MyApp.run!  if $0 == __FILE__
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have these lines in your `Gemfile`

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'
gem 'sinatra'
```

Then:

```
bundle
```

Then:

```
git push heroku master
```

Comment: It's a Sinatra app, not Rails, so why should he have the Rails gem?

Comment: Hm, yeah that seems to be what he tried already. At least he claims to have followed this: http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rack

Comment: Right. But that error comes from not having an app version declared in bundler.

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me. It turned out it was because I initialized the Git repository in myproject/myapp/. Heroku needs the Git repository to be in myapp/. I deleted the .git folder in myproject/ (thus deleting that repository) and ran

```
cd myapp
git init
```

After that, it worked great.